# Как экспортировать удаленный объект на порт созданный на Сервере?

Tags: java, rmi

```
Сервер:
final int PORT = 1099;
            try {
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Клиент:

```
try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
            Stub stub = new StubImpl();
            UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(stub, 1099);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Ошибка что порт уже используется.**
Для чего мне это нужно? Я хочу создать "многопоточный" клиент сервер. Т.е. каждый раз подключаясь клиент должен передать удаленный объект реализованный на клиенте, чтобы сервер смог вызывать методы из этого интерфейса.

Comment: RMI многопоточен по умолчанию, никаких дополнительных телодвижений для этого не требуется.

Comment: я знаю. Я хочу удаленный объект передать на сервер чтобы его там вызвать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Проблема в том, что я не могу по тому же порту передать объект..

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Если взять другой порт, а на сервере уже ловить его, то так получается, но тут другая проблема: при подключении каждого клиента нужно будет брать новый порт, это абсурд.

Comment: У вас клиент и сервер на одной машине запущены?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Всё, понял.. Спасибо.

Comment: Кроме того, не проблема клиенту вешать экспортируемый объект на случайный непривилегированный порт. Он же этот объект всё равно зарегистрирует по имени в rmiregistry, откуда другой узел сможет его получить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Если вам не сложно, покажите как реализовать в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как в вашей схеме клиенты тоже экспортируют объекты, а значит тоже являются серверами, не будем называть узлы клиентами и сервером. Пусть будет центральный узел (на хосте с именем "controller") и периферийные узлы.

Логично запустить rmiregistry на том же хосте, где запущен центральный узел. Тогда в коде периферийного узла подключение к реестру надо подправить так:

```
String localHostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("controller");
StubImpl stub = new StubImpl();
Stub exported = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(stub, 0);
registry.rebind(localHostName + ".Hello", exported);
```

А в том месте кода центрального узла, где нужно вызывать удалённый метод периферийных узлов делать что-нибудь вроде:

```
for(String obj : Registry.list()) {
    Stub stub = (Stub) Registry.lookup(obj);
    stub.remoteMethod();
}
```